# How can i set focus on a text box to prevent the page from posting?

Tags: jquery

I’m trying to use a simple piece of jquery code that checks the contents  textbox then if the contents are not valid prevent the page from posting.  I thought that using a wet focus or select would do the trick but the page still gets posted.  How can I change this code to re-focus on the textbox until the correct entry is made.  Here’s a simplified version of what I’ve been trying:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">


         $(document).ready(function () {
             $('#saveBtn').click(function () {
                 var trial = $('#HomeworkGrade').val();


                 if (trial == 77) {
                     alert('Correct entry')
                 }
                 else {
                     alert('Incorrect entry');
                     $('#HomeworkGrade').focus();

                 }

             })

         });




        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to intercept the `submit` event on your form instead of the click event on the button, and return `false` from the event handler to prevent the default action:

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $('#myForm').submit(function () {   // attach handler to the form here.
             var trial = $('#HomeworkGrade').val();
             if (trial == 77) {
                 alert('Correct entry');
                 return true;              // permit submit
             }
             else {
                 alert('Incorrect entry');
                 $('#HomeworkGrade').focus();
                 return false;            // prevent submit
             }
         })
     });
```